# HTML input set type from value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

Is there any known way of getting the input tag type by checking the default value set for that input?

i.e. if the input default value is set to true or false the input type should be checkbox and the same for date and all other types

here is the code that I want to detect the field value (there are date props and bool props, but they are all rendered as type text input)

```
Object.keys(user).map(key => <h4>{key} : <input type="auto-detect" value={user[key]} /></h4>)
```

And this is the value of `user` that I get from the api

```
{
  id: 18273009, // input type="number"
  firstName: "admin", // input type="text"
  lastName: "user", // input type="text"
  email: "admin@gmail.com", // input type="email"
  phone: "9178888888", // input type="tel"
  address: "123 abc Dr", // input type="text"
  isLogged: "b2e74b00-e1a6-44bd-833f-7dba2e98c10e", // input type="text"
  loginTime: "2022-04-12T17:20:00.2176106", // input type="datetime"
  dateJoined: "2022-03-30T14:12:13.1303726", // input type="datetime"
  isMember: false, // input type="checkbox"
  isAdmin: false, // input type="checkbox"
  isSysAdmin: false, // input type="checkbox"
  planType: "Free", // input type="text"
  streamsToday: 194, // input type="number"
  listIpAddress: [], // don't render, or render <select>
}
```

Comment: There's no standard way to go that roundabout process you'll need to write a function. Why not `$('input')[0].type`  or `$('input').attr('type')`?

Comment: What’s the source of the default value you’re receiving, an Array of values, the document itself, something else?

Comment: @DavidThomas added the code, `user` is an object received from an api

Comment: Why would true or false be the default value for a checkbox? That's not standard.

Comment: @Barmar Because if `user[key]` is equals true or false, that means that this property is type Boolean,  so the default type would be checkbox.

Comment: Can you post a representative example of the Object you receive from the API call? *And* the exact result you'd want returned after processing that Object?

Comment: @bigboy I didn't understand that you were talking about a value from an object, I thought you meant something about the HTML `<input>` element.

Comment: @DavidThomas added an object example

Comment: @bigboy the email key and phone key do not have a email or tel value.

Comment: While it was somewhat possible to determine whether the `<input>` elemt's `type` should be a `"checkbox"` or not, based on the Boolean nature of `true`/`false` ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/q46fogcs/)), the other types, and requirements, make this more difficult; and - honestly - far more prone to mistakes than necessary. And this is one of those situations where all that detail really needed to be in the question to begin with (but that's the nature of learning, mistakes will be made at first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Create Form Controls

***from an Object Literal Key/Value Pairs***

A few values from `user` object are invalid (you should at least put an email address for `email` and 10 digits for `phone`). So I have corrected and modified `user` object so it can simulate real data.

`type="datetime"` is deprecated, use [`type="datetime-local"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local)

**Figure I**

In the example below are 7 functions:

| Function | Purpose |
| --- | --- |
| `formatDate(d)` | <sup>Date values must be formatted before being set to a `type="datetime-local"` input.</sup> |
| `typeFilter(k, v)` | <sup>Determines what type of form control should be used according to value.</sup> |
| `formControl(k, v, t)` | <sup>Generates an object for each key/value. Each object has a value of a htmlString of a form control</sup> |
| `userData(o)` | <sup>Processes returns from `typeFilter()` and `formControl()` and will return a single object that contains all of the htmlSrings.</sup> |
| `parseHTML(h, n, p=)` | <sup>Parses htmlString into real HTML.</sup> |
| `makeLabel(n, p=)` | <sup>Creates a `<label>`</sup> |
| `setID(n, a=)` | <sup>Set's/changes attributes of an element</sup> |

***Details are commented in example below***

```js
const user = {
  idn: 18273009, // input type="number"
  first: 'Zer0', // input type="text"
  last: '0ne', // input type="text"
  email: 'admin@mail.com', // input type="email"
  phone: 14085551234, // input type="tel"
  address: '1234 Main St. Springfield, IL 62777', // textarea
  logHash: 'b2e74b00-e1a6-44bd-833f-7dba2e98c10e', // textarea
  timeLogin: '2022-04-12T17:20:00.2176106', // input type="datetime-local"
  dateJoined: '2022-03-30T14:12:13.1303726', // input type="datetime-local"
  isMember: true, // input type="checkbox"
  isAdmin: false, // input type="checkbox"
  isSysAdmin: false, // input type="checkbox"
  servicePlan: 'Free', // input type="text"
  currentStreams: 194, // input type="number"
  listIpAddress: ['127.0.0.1', '155.120.3.2', '213.11.77.6'], // select
};

/**
* timeLogin and dateJoined values must be formatted in
* in order to be assigned as a value of an
* <input type="datetime-local">
* LINE 90
*/
const formatDate = (dateTime) => {
  const d = new Date(dateTime);
  d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() - d.getTimezoneOffset());
  return d.toISOString().slice(0, 16);
};

/**
* A <key/value> pair is passed and a <key/value/tag> trine is 
* returned. It checks values to determine which type of
* form control is needed. A string selector of a tagName or
* a string value of the type property is the <tag> of a 
* return.
* Line 122
*/ 
const typeFilter = (key, val) => {
  return Array.isArray(val)
    ? [key, val, 'select']
    : Number.isInteger(val) &&
      val.toString().length === 11 &&
      val.toString().charAt(0) === '1'
    ? [key, val, 'tel']
    : val.valueOf() === true || val.valueOf() === false
    ? [key, val, 'checkbox']
    : val.toString().includes('@')
    ? [key, val, 'email']
    : Number.isInteger(val)
    ? [key, val, 'number']
    : Date.parse(val)
    ? [key, val, 'datetime-local']
    : typeof val === 'string' && val.length >= 20
    ? [key, val, 'textarea']
    : [key, val, 'text'];
};

/**
* Passes <key/value/tag> trine and returns an array of objects
* -- each object contains a key and htmlString value. Each
* htmlString represents a form control:
* ex. <input name="<key>" type="<tag>" value="<value>">
* LINE 134
*/
const formControl = (key, value, tag) => {
  const html = {};
  let htmlStr;

  switch (tag) {
    case 'select':
      htmlStr = `<select name="${key}"><option selected>Select an option</option>`;
      value.forEach((val) => (htmlStr += `<option>${val}</option>`));
      html[key] = htmlStr + `</select>`;
      break;
    case 'tel':
      let val = '' + value;
      let hyphenated = val
        .split('')
        .map((n, i) =>
          i === 1 
          ? '-' + n 
              : i === 4 
              ? '-' + n 
              : i === 7 
              ? '-' + n 
              : n
        )
        .join('');
      htmlStr = `<input name='${key}' type='tel' value='${hyphenated}'>`;
      html[key] = htmlStr;
      break;
    case 'checkbox':
      let end = value === true ? ` checked>` : ` >`;
      htmlStr = `<input name='${key}' type='checkbox'` + end;
      html[key] = htmlStr;
      break;
    case 'email':
      htmlStr = `<input name='${key}' type='email' value='${value}'>`;
      html[key] = htmlStr;
      break;
    case 'number':
      htmlStr = `<input name='${key}' type='number' value='${value}'>`;
      html[key] = htmlStr;
      break;
    case 'datetime-local':
      let dateTime = formatDate(value);
      htmlStr = `<input name='${key}' type='datetime-local' value='${dateTime}'>`;
      html[key] = htmlStr;
      break;
    case 'textarea':
      htmlStr = `<textarea name='${key}' rows='3' cols='20'>${value}</textarea>`;
      html[key] = htmlStr;
      break;
    case 'text':
      htmlStr = `<input name='${key}' type='text' value='${value}'>`;
      html[key] = htmlStr;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  return html;
};

/**
* This is the main function that passes in the <user> object 
* and returns a modified <user> object -- the values are 
* htmlStrings of form controls with the original values embeded
* in the htmlStrings.
*/
const userData = (obj) => {
  let types = [];
  /*
  - Converts <user> object into an array of pairs.
  - On each iteration, the return of typeFilter() is stored in
    an array <types>.
  */
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    types.push(typeFilter(key, value));
  }
  // console.log(types);
  /*
  - The <types> array is ran through with .map() and .reduce()
  - .map() will run formControl() on each trine of <types> --
    the return value is an object with one key and one value.
  - .reduce() will merge all of those objects into a single
    object
  - The single object is then returned.
  */
  let html = types
    .map(([key, value, tag]) => formControl(key, value, tag))
    .reduce((obj, htm) => Object.assign(obj, htm), {});
  // console.log(html);
  return html;
};

/**
* Just a wrapper for .insertAdjacentHTML(). 
* @param position is optional, if not defined it defaults to 
* 'beforeend'.
*/
const parseHTML = (htmlString, node, position = 'beforeend') => {
  node.insertAdjacentHTML(position, htmlString);
}; 

/**
* Creates a <label> with a formatted name of the element it is 
* paired with.
*/
const makeLabel = (node, position = 'beforebegin') => {
  let text = node.name.replace(/.*?([A-Z][a-z]*)/g, ' $1');
  parseHTML(`<br><label>${text}: </label>`, node, position);
  if (node.matches('textarea')) {
    const vert = node.previousElementSibling;
    vert.style.verticalAlign = 'top';
  }
};

/**
* Sets any given attribute's value of a given element. Note, the
* second @param is an array that should have the attribute's
* name and value. If not defined, then it will pass a default:
* ex. ['id', 'IDN18273009x1650056016986']
* The value is "IDN"(user.idn)"x"(UNIX timestamp)
*/
const setID = (node, attr = ['id', 'IDN' + user.idn +'x'+ Date.now()]) =>
  node.setAttribute(attr[0], attr[1]);

const html = userData(user);

parseHTML(`<form></form>`, document.body);

const F = document.forms[0];
const FC = F.elements;

parseHTML(html.listIpAddress, F);
parseHTML(html.isMember, F);
parseHTML(html.isSysAdmin, F);
parseHTML(html.address, F);
parseHTML(html.phone, F);

const ipList = FC.listIpAddress;
const member = FC.isMember;
const sysAdmin = FC.isSysAdmin;
const address = FC.address;
const phone = FC.phone;

makeLabel(ipList);
makeLabel(member);
makeLabel(sysAdmin);
makeLabel(address);
makeLabel(phone);

parseHTML(html.dateJoined, ipList, 'afterend');
const joined = FC.dateJoined;
makeLabel(joined);
setID(F);
```

```css
html {
  font: 2ch/1 'Segoe UI';
}
input,
textarea,
select,
label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0.5rem 0.5rem 0;
  font: inherit;
}
label {
  vertical-align: baseline;
  min-width: 9ch;
  text-align: right;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
[type='checkbox'] {
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
[type='tel'] {
  width: 13.5ch;
}
```

Comment: Thank for putting in the work!

Answer (score 0):

Deciding the types based on the values alone is not feasible. Cases in point - consider that both `firstName` and `email` have value `admin`. So something along the following lines would suffice.

```js
function autoDetectInputType ( { key, value } ) {
    
    // a switch statement would be fine as well if you like

    if ( key === 'email' ) return 'email';

    if ( /(?:time|date)/.test( key ) ) return 'datetime';

    if ( 'number' === typeof ( value ) ) return 'number';

    // and so on and so forth...
}
```